# .lua files seem to have been corrupted

Tags: encoding, lua, character-encoding

I am trying to open Lua scripts written by another person. While a number of them look well, there others which are displayed like in the first screenshot.

I can't understand what encoding to use to open these files. Windows notepad seems to be using ANSI when opening them but also no luck. Is there a way to reed these files correctly?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This appears to be bytecode, use a decompiler (e.g. luac or unluac) to read

Comment: Compiling source into bytecode is different from applying some character encoding.  But the result is similar: you see gibberish instead of readable text :-)